# Do forum or website exist where can buy things not usually sold with bitcoin?

Tags: websites, marketplace, silk-road

Something like "wanted" classified advertisements is needed. Silk Road only sell offensive merchandise, no method to post wanted ads. Interested in purchase electronics, other legal unobjectionable products. Does website like this exist?

Comment: If you wish to have something specific bought for you, there are many people willing to facilitate this.  If it is simply a matter of placing an online order with your address, that is easy. If it needs to be re-shipped to you (e.g., seller doesn't ship to your country), that can be arranged as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Marketplace on BitcoinTalk can be used.  Simply prefix your post's title with "[WTB]" which means "Want To Buy".

Discussion:

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=64607.0

Marketplace board:

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=5.0

Also, the Bitcoin-otc marketplace can be used to place requests, if you are looking to buy.

- http://bitcoin-otc.com/vieworderbook.php

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin classifieds 
http://www.bitcoinclassifieds.net/

Music & other digital goods at
http://www.coindl.com

Answer (score 0):

You can [buy and sell songs and albums on Bitcoin at Liberty Music Store](http://libertymusicstore.net/).

It is 100% legal and geared towards indie artists.